# rtconner/laravel-likeable sort after number of likes

Tags: laravel-5.1

Using this package https://github.com/rtconner/laravel-likeable I want to do a sort of the articles after the number of likes. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: a query for this purpose would be SELECT * FROM articles LEFT JOIN likeable_like_counters on articles.id = likeable_like_counters.likable_id order by likeable_like_counters.count desc;

Answer (score 0):

```
$articles = Article::with('likeCounter')
                ->leftJoin('likeable_like_counters', 'aforisms.id', '=', 'likeable_like_counters.likable_id')
                ->select('articles.*', 'likeable_like_counters.likable_id', 'likeable_like_counters.count')
                ->orderBy('likeable_like_counters.count', 'desc')
                ->paginate(40);
```